# Limit (Restrict) app installations per account (detemined by unique devices) in Android

Tags: android, google-play

I have published an Android app.

Problem is, if someone buys my app, he can install it on several devices using the same account.

Can I limit the installation to a few (let's say 2) unique devices per account?

If the user wants to use it on another device with the same account, he will have to uninstall from another one first.

For example, [MyBackup Pro only allows two unique devices.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rerware.android.MyBackupPro&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5yZXJ3YXJlLmFuZHJvaWQuTXlCYWNrdXBQcm8iXQ)

How can I achieve this in my app?

Comment: Most users would probably expect that the app will work on all of their devices. If you have a reason like MyBackup Pro (e.g. each device adds to storage and transfer cost) then I think as long as you make it clear before a user purchases then it is fine. If you don't have a reason to limit devices like that, I would say don't do it so as to not detract from the user experience.

Answer (score 13):

[Google helps you do this](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html).

[This page helps you set it up.](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html)

More specifically, [it looks like you want to add a DeviceLimiter](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html#impl-DeviceLimiter):

> In some cases, you might want your Policy to limit the number of
>   actual devices that are permitted to use a single license. This would
>   prevent a user from moving a licensed application onto a number of
>   devices and using the application on those devices under the same
>   account ID. It would also prevent a user from "sharing" the
>   application by providing the account information associated with the
>   license to other individuals, who could then sign in to that account
>   on their devices and access the license to the application.
>
> The LVL supports per-device licensing by providing a DeviceLimiter
>   interface, which declares a single method, allowDeviceAccess(). When a
>   LicenseValidator is handling a response from the licensing server, it
>   calls allowDeviceAccess(), passing a user ID string extracted from the
>   response.
>
> If you do not want to support device limitation, no work is required —
>   the LicenseChecker class automatically uses a default implementation
>   called NullDeviceLimiter. As the name suggests, NullDeviceLimiter is a
>   "no-op" class whose allowDeviceAccess() method simply returns a
>   LICENSED response for all users and devices.
>
> Caution: Per-device licensing is not recommended for most applications
>   because:
>
> It requires that you provide a backend server to manage a users and
>   devices mapping, and It could inadvertently result in a user being
>   denied access to an application that they have legitimately purchased
>   on another device.

The source code for `DeviceLimiter` [can be found here.](https://code.google.com/r/android-dev-marketlicensing/source/browse/library/src/com/android/vending/licensing/DeviceLimiter.java?r=9cd599d6902d8b9b8311e4ef8dd20dcccb5e7aba&spec=svn4fe2c52435d8e4ad7d8a47e086b633439f9a8fa6)

The source pretty much explains how you'd go about using DeviceLimiter to implement what you want:

```
/* The LICENSED response from the server contains a user identifier unique to
 * the <application, user> pair. The developer can send this identifier
 * to their own server along with some device identifier (a random number
 * generated and stored once per application installation,
 * {@link android.telephony.TelephonyManager#getDeviceId getDeviceId},
 * {@link android.provider.Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID ANDROID_ID}, etc).
 *
 * The more sources used to identify the device, the harder it will be for an
 * attacker to spoof.
```

Answer (score 3):

Both Ascorbin and yarian answers are nice to explain.

As per my knowledge It can be managed by two ways.

**1. By Google it self**

**2. By your own implementation**

Lets check one by one,

**1. By Google it Self**

Ascorbin's answer explain well how to implement it and How google manage it. So hope you got it. If not then let me know.

**2. By your own implementation**

If you have your own server then you can put code which check for the installed app devices. Every Device have unique IMEI number so you can easily track the same IMEI number and block or allow the installation of the app or working of the app.

**Note:** Google allows you to use same app in another device if the device has configured same account. so in that case it can be only possible by detecting same account with different IMEI or MAC address.

Hope you got the point.

Feel free to comment.  :)

Comment: Note that beginning with android 10 you cannot access IMEI or other device identifiers with your app (system apps only). You will need to create your own ID (maybe from login data if you have a login) or use something like firebase that can provide an id.

Answer (score 2):

You can identify the device for example via the MAC adress of the wlan module or by the IMEI (both can be retrieved via Android system services). Next is you identify the installation with your server, if the server replies that this user/ customer has already installed this on another device, you lock the app and tell the user what's up.

Comment: I don't want to maintain a server for this. I would prefer to check if Google allows this with their manifest or Servers (as google Licsensing does)

Comment: How would one installation of your app know that there's already another installation of the app on another device? Google could provide such a feature but I don't think they do.

Comment: I have already used google Licsencing. They provide a server, and the program checks if the file is copied from one machine to another, and it does so with google server services (checks if this machine or account bought this app). I want this server to also limit legal purchases and not just pirating

Comment: +1 Using a server is the only way to do this. You can't maintain a list of all devices on each device - you need to query somewhere.

Comment: it is not possible. I cannot know within my server if a program was uninstalled (so to free the row in my server), only google knows that