# Does a user lose their in app purchase if they uninstall the app?

Tags: android

I'm thinking of implementing in app billing instead of releasing a separate app with the pro features. and I'm wondering if the user would lose their purchase if they uninstall or factory reset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use the in app billing api from google, the purchase is bound to the users google account.

that means, as long as they use the same account, they have access to the purchased features

you can find more informations here http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#purchase

Comment: But what if the app doesn't require for the user to sign up using there google account ?

Comment: Afaik it is the play services that manage the purchases. so your app does not require to login. the user is already signed on the device so the play services can validate the purchase

Answer (score 1):

Applications are tight to the account and can be installed multiple times on multiple devices. See this [article](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113410).

Comment: Can we control that once application installed on one mobile. After than can not install that same app in another mobile until and unless user pay for it.

Comment: Yes, it is possible restrict purchase to only one device, but it's not the default behavior.

Comment: Can you please share your knowledge or give any link how can i do that.?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064563/limit-restrict-app-installations-per-account-detemined-by-unique-devices-in