# Set devicelimiter for ios app same as android

Tags: android, ios, device

I want to develop one ios application where i can set DeviceLimiter same as android provides.

[Limit (Restrict) app installations per account (detemined by unique devices) in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064563/limit-restrict-app-installations-per-account-detemined-by-unique-devices-in/15221183#15221183)

Comment: i think question should be in understandable format. for the better option i have given ref link also that android is providing such feature.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in iOS with the App Store alone. A user may install an app on any number of devices that are associated with their iTunes Store account.

I have seen some apps where the app is a free download and there is a "subscription" per device manager (and paid for) on a web site.