# Android payment on each device

Tags: android, android-pay

I have a app that the ambition is to be executed on multiple devices on the same account. The problem is that it payments must be made by per amount of devices it is installed on. Or a Payment like 1-10 devices, 11-20 devices.

At the same time, the ambition is to be able to use Google Play to make it possible to push out updates on the app to all devices at once. But that is in conflict with the Google Play's terms of payments.

I only found how to restrict the app on some devices, but not how to make it possible to take payments per device.
[Limit (Restrict) app installations per account (detemined by unique devices) in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064563/limit-restrict-app-installations-per-account-detemined-by-unique-devices-in)

Are there a solution to make payments per device, and still use Google Play, or are there any other solution?